# Python Average Rainfall, how to get yearly average?

Tags: python

### On this program I have it set to get the overall average of all the years if more than 1, but how do I get the separate yearly averages?

```
total_months = 0

rainfall_inches = 0

years = int(input("How many years of data do you wish to collect? "))

for currentYear in range(1, years + 1):

    for currentMonth in range(1, 13):

        monthly_rainfall = float(input("Enter the inches of rainfall for month " 
+ format(currentMonth, "d") + ", year " + format(currentYear,"d") + 
": "))

        rainfall_inches += monthly_rainfall

        total_months += 1


avg_rainfall = rainfall_inches / total_months

print("Number of months: " + format(total_months, "d"), "Total inches of `
rainfall: " + format(rainfall_inches, ".2f"), "Average rainfall: " + `
format(avg_rainfall, ".2f"), sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a yearly_avgs list and update it in your outer for loop, and find the total average from that list as opposed to using total_months. For example:

```
yearly_avgs = []                       # initialize list for yearly averages
total_months = 0
rainfall_inches = 0
years = int(input("How many years of data do you wish to collect? "))

for currentYear in range(1, years + 1):
  for currentMonth in range(1, 13):
    monthly_rainfall = float(input("Enter the inches of rainfall for month "
    + \
    format(currentMonth, "d") + ", year " + format(currentYear,"d") +
    ": "))
    rainfall_inches += monthly_rainfall
    total_months += 1
  yearly_avgs += rainfall_inches       # append average for currentYear
  rainfall_inches = 0                  # reset rainfall_inches

avg_rainfall = sum(yearly_avgs)/years  # get average over years

print("Number of months: " + format(total_months, "d"), "Total inches of `
rainfall: " + format(rainfall_inches, ".2f"), "Average rainfall: " + `
format(avg_rainfall, ".2f"), sep="\n")
```

It's still a little clunky but it gets the job done, I think.